# JQuery animating batch of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Hi Ive been trying a quite simple animation on my webpage but somehow cannot achieve the desired result.

Here is my page http://sisphoto.eu/actions.php. What I`m trying to do is make each image appear at their resulting position and make them animate one at a time,  not all at once.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="left">
            <span class="name">
                <a href="index.php"><img class="menu" src="name.png"/></a>
            </span>
            <span class="img">
                <img src="actions/p30.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"/>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <span class="img">
                <img src="actions/p1.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"/>
            </span>
            <span class="img">
                <img src="actions/p4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"/>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <span class="img">
                <img src="actions/p5.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"/>
            </span>
            <span class="img">
                <img src="actions/p6.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"/>
            </span>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .left, .middle, .right{
    /*max-width: 35%;*/
    min-width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 2.5em;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.left{
    left: 0;
}

.middle{
    left: 300;
}

.right{
    left: 600;
}

.img {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-out; 
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

$(function () {
    var delay = 300;
    $('.right, .middle, .left').each(function () {
        var imgs = $('.img'),
            iLen = imgs.length;

        imgs.each(function () {
            var c = $(this), 
                h = c.height();

            delay += 10;
            setTimeout(function () {
                c.css('max-width', '100%');
                c.css('opacity', '1');
            }, delay);

        });
    });
});
```

any help?

Comment: Why not remove `$('.right, .middle, .left').each(function () {` and use `$('.img').each()` >?

Comment: I can't do that because I have another image elements that I don't want to animate in the same way

Comment: so instead of giving them the same class name as other elements give them a class name of `.home_images` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all images and animate the images with a delay. The delay is the 
`animationspeed * count`

of the current image.

```js
var animationspeed = 300;
var count = 0;

$('.animate_image').shuffle().each( function() {
  $(this).delay(animationspeed * count).animate({ }, animationspeed);
  count+=1;
});

(function($){
 
$.fn.shuffle = function() {
 
    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
       });
 
    this.each(function(i){
        $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });
 
    return $(shuffled);
 
};
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.animate_image {
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```

EDIT: instead of the 'img' selector use a class selector like '.animate_image'. Add a class to an image like this:

Comment: That sounds interesting but again I cannot do it for each image because I have images there that I wish not to be animated in a same way...

Comment: why didnt it come to me? thanks... one more thing how could i do it semi-randomized... like they wouldnt load simply from top to bottom but semi random... or at least not by columns but by rows

Comment: i edited the post with a shuffle function. If i answered your question please check my answer as the solution for other users with the same problem